# Search list to a filtered form ms-access

Tags: ms-access, filtering

So I have set up a form that can search through multiple fields using the Dynamic Multi Search tool found [here](https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/threads/dynamically-search-multiple-fields.188663/). Currently it uses a list box with on OnDoubleClick event to open in another form a single record from the search list by using the following

```
Private Sub SearchResults_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)

    Dim stDocName As String
    Dim stLinkCriteria As String

    stDocName = "frm_MainEntryForm"

    stLinkCriteria = "[ID_UniqueID]=" & Me![SearchResults]
    DoCmd.OpenForm stDocName, , , stLinkCriteria

End Sub
```

Ideally I would have an option to open ALL the records found. I guess this would be achieved by somehow filtering the form where the ID_UniqueID column of the form matches all the values in the ID_UniqueID column of the search results box.

Is this even possible? I'm not sure how to set this up or where to start? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Can build an "ALL" option into listbox RowSource with a UNION query.

Because there are no apostrophe delimiters built into search criteria, I presume ID_uniqueID is a number field which users don't see and instead see descriptive alias:

```
SELECT 0, "ALL" AS Data FROM tablename
UNION SELECT ID_UniqueID, fieldname FROM tablename;
```

Then code tests if 0 is selected item:

```
If Me.SearchResults <> 0 Then
    stLinkCriteria = "[ID_UniqueID]=" & Me![SearchResults]
End If
```

For another approach to building search criteria, review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html.